# Sliced citrus in a pie?

Tags: pie, oranges, citrus

I've been considering making an orange pie - but something generally closer to e.g. an apple or pear pie than a key-lime. Something with distinct slices, not a custard(-ish) filling. From a cursory search, though, I can't find anything of the sort - no baked slices or chunks of any citrus. Is this a thing that can reasonably be done?

Comment: Would the filling be baked in like an apple pie or a raw filling in a baked crust like a strawberry pie? I've certainly seen orange or mandarin wedges on fruit tarts. Or there's something like [this](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/blood-orange-tart-with-cardamom-pastry-cream-104613).

Comment: Try searching on 'caramelized orange tart' or 'Valencia orange tart' for some good options which use thinly-sliced oranges.

Comment: Candying the slices could work... mind that strong acids mess with gluten in unholy ways when experimenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching for shaker lemon pie. You can also find a couple recipes for "shaker orange pie" but the lemon version is the more common one.

It definitely works well with lemon. If the recipes specifically with orange don't work out, you could also try starting with a shaker lemon pie recipe, replacing the lemons with oranges, then adding lemon juice and reducing the sugar to rebalance the sour and sweet. (I don't think you can just cut the sugar really drastically; there's generally enough of it to contribute to the texture, not just sweetness.)